# C Programming on printing a string backwords using pointers

Tags: c, string, reverse

My program will obtain a string of characters from the user and print the sentence backwards it will continue to ask the user for another string until the string is equal to quit. The problem I am having is when the user enters quit it continues with the loop when I want it to just print "thank you." I have no idea why the if and else statements aren't working for when the user enters quit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char chr;
    char *cPtr;
    char someString[50];
    int stringSize;
    int indx;

    printf("Enter a string of characters: ");
    cPtr = someString;

    while ((chr = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        *cPtr = chr;
        cPtr++;
    }
    *cPtr = '\0';

    stringSize = strlen(someString);

    if (someString == "quit" )
    {
        printf("Thank you.");
    }
    else
    {
        while (someString != "quit")
        {
            for (indx = stringSize; indx >= 0; indx--)
            {
                printf("%c",*cPtr--);
            }

            printf("\nEnter a string of characters: ");
            cPtr = someString;

            while ((chr=getchar())!= '\n')
            {
                *cPtr = chr;
                cPtr++;
            }
            *cPtr = '\0';

            stringSize = strlen(someString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`if (someString == "quit" )` is not comparing the two string content. It is comparing their addresses, which are always different. Use the `strcmp` function instead. Same for `while (someString != "quit")`

Comment: temp = strcmp(someString, safeWord);
    printf("%d", temp);
    if ( temp == 0 )
    {
        printf("Thank you.");
    }


    else
    {
        while (  temp != 0  )                                                                      I have changed it to look like this but I still get a negative value when I enter in quit.

Comment: safeWord I have assigned as "quit"

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the fact that when it produces an output there is a space before the reversed string.